# How to get InputStream from Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using Hibernate 5.6.7 with spring-data-jpa 2.6.3.

I've a table with a column "file" which contain binary data (.pdf, .docx, ...).

**These files can be larger than my heap size, so I need to stream them to my consumer.
How can I get these file as a stream from Hibernate ?**

For now I define an entity as following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "fjd")
public class FJTContent implements Serializable {


    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "file")
    @Type(type="org.hibernate.type.BlobType")
    public Blob fichier;
}
```

Then I define a Jpa repository :

```
public interface FJTContentRepository extends JpaRepository<FJTContent , Integer> {

}
```

But when I try to get the stream (`InputStream is = myRepo.getById(id).getFichier().getBinaryStream();`) I got an error

```
02/08/2022 12:05:34.667 [ERROR] gldbackendv2 -[http-nio-8080-exec-4]-   -  - f.u.i.e.ExceptionControllerAdvice - Exception : 
org.hibernate.exception.DataException: Could not read entity state from ResultSet : EntityKey[fr.foo.bar.repository.entity.FJTContent #1]
...
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Bad value for type long : \xd0cf11e0a1b11
```

Comment: I do believe that won't work in JPA/HBN domain, the problem is LOB is valid till closing DB cursor. When you get control from HBN and may work with entity DB cursor is already closed, and so all LOBs are invalid. You need something JDBC-based.

Comment: What is the column DDL type for `file`? For streaming it must be `oid`. You'll have to keep the transaction open until you are done with streaming the data, which is best done by annotating your controller method with `@Transactional`

Answer (score 0):

Below is "something jdbc-based" (spring-jdbc):

```java
public Consumer<InputStream> pusher(Integer id) {
    return is -> {
        String statement = "update fjd set file = :content where id = :id";
        NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(this.jdbcTemplate);
        MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        parameters.addValue("id", id);
        parameters.addValue("content", new SqlLobValue(is, guessStreamSize(is)), Types.BLOB);
        jdbcTemplate.update(statement, parameters);
    };
}

public Consumer<OutputStream> puller(Integer id) {
    return os -> {
        RowMapper<Void> rowMapper = (rs, rowNum) -> withBlob(rs, is -> copy(is, os));
        String statement = "select file from fjd where id = :id";
        MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        parameters.addValue("id", id);
        NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(this.jdbcTemplate);
        jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(statement, parameters, rowMapper);
    };
}

@SneakyThrows
protected Void withBlob(ResultSet rs, Consumer<InputStream> consumer) {
    LobHandler lobHandler = new DefaultLobHandler();
    try (InputStream is = lobHandler.getBlobAsBinaryStream(rs, "file")) {
        consumer.accept(is);
        return null;
    }
}

@SneakyThrows
protected long copy(InputStream in, OutputStream out) {
    return IOUtils.copy(in, out);
}

protected int guessStreamSize(InputStream is) {
    Dialect dialect = getDialect();
    if (dialect instanceof Oracle8iDialect) {
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
    return -1;
}

protected Dialect getDialect() {
    return entityManager.unwrap(SharedSessionContractImplementor.class)
            .getJdbcServices().getDialect();
}
```

usage:

```java
try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("path")) {
    pusher(123).accept(fis);
}

try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("path")) {
    puller(123).accept(fos);
}
```